# Sometimes one of started processes from the list is stuck and blocking whole program

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have problem with stuck process. My code is looking like this:

```
        for message in response.received_messages:
            process = multiprocessing.Process(
                target=self.process_task,
                args=(message.message, callback),
            )
            processes[process] = (message.ack_id, message.message.data)
            process.start()

        while processes:
            for process in list(processes):
                ack_id, msg_data = processes[process]
                if process.is_alive():
                    continue
                else:
                    self.subscriber_client.acknowledge(
                        subscription_path,
                        [ack_id],
                    )
                    processes.pop(process)
```

Everything is working fine, I'm procsessing max 5 messages at once but sometimes one process stuck and blocking my whole program and I don't know why. After restart when I push message with same arguments like stucked process it finish task without any problems.
I noticed that every time when process stuck htop shows that one core is working on 100%. Any ideas what can cause this? Or maybe I should make something like custom timeout to terminate stuck process?

Comment: I don't think it would help, but instead of this rather complicated while loop, why not put `self.subscriber_client.acknowledge` inside `callback` or `self.process_task` so that the process itself just does that when it finishes? It would simplify things a lot and probably avoid errors. For example, if the process fails with an exception, do you still want to acknowledge? It seems like that's what this code does and it sounds bad. Other than that, put some logging or printing inside `self.process_task` to see what it's doing.

Comment: Thanks for a hint! I just found really bad writen `try: except:` in `self.process_task`, I fix it and put `self.subscriber_client.acknowledge` to this method as you said. Now I'm testing new code and i hope it would help.